# Lucene search not working after an update

Tags: search, lucene

I am using Lucene 4.6 API. Here is a scenario that I am grappling with:

1. I create an object in my database and index it into Lucene using:

   indexWriter.updateDocument( new Term( Indexer.FIELD_ID, id ), doc, new StandardAnalyzer( Version.LUCENE_46 ) );

where Doc has a single text field. (Initial content is: `s-150129-00023 descriptionold admin addsdi admin editsdi initial unknown` )

2. I do a search using the string `decriptionold` and it works fine
3. I update the same object in my database, and update the description which in turn calls

   indexWriter.updateDocument( new Term( Indexer.FIELD_ID, id ), doc, new StandardAnalyzer( Version.LUCENE_46 ) );

where Doc is again a single text field with content: ( `s-150129-00023 descriptionnew admin addsdi admin editsdi initial unknown` )

4. Now when i do a search, i do find a match for `descriptionnew` - however i do get a match for `descriptionold` as well. I would expect `descriptionold` to not return any matches, but it does.

I did make sure i called `indexWriter.close()` after calling `updateDocument()`, 
I also tried calling `forceMergeDeletes()`, `waitMergeDeletes()` etc. but it makes no difference.

Any pointers on what i am missing?

Comment: Are you sure the "id" is being found?  Have you tried searching for it to see what happens (ex:  `new TermQuery(new Term( Indexer.FIELD_ID, id))`)?  Also, are you creating an entirely new document for the update call in step 3, or updating an instance from a search?